# How-to render pages like Safari on OS X, while on Windows

Tags: css, windows, macos, safari

For some time now I have been struggling with the differences between the Mac and Windows version of Safari. Sadly, my develop-setup requires me to work on Windows (although I do work on a MBP), so I can't change stuff and look how it affects the rendering of the page. Updating the online testing environment every time I make a change is silly.

The solution renders fine in Chrome (Windows+Mac), Firefox (Windows+Mac) and.. Even Internet Explorer.

So, my question is: is there a way to make Safari on Windows behave as if it were on OS X?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install a virtual machine running OSX:
http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/05/os-x-mavericks-in-virtualbox-with-niresh.html

I'm not sure how else you would be able to do it through windows.

Comment: I have heard/read of the supposed solution before, but I was kind-of hoping that there would be another way :(